# Calculating trailing zero in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i calculate the number of trailing zeros in a factorial of a given number.

```
N! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 ... N
```

Any Help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because zeros come from factors 5 and 2 being multiplied together, iterate over all numbers from `1` to the input number, adding to a cumulative count of fives and twos whenever those factors are found. Then, return the smaller of those two counts:

```js
function zeroCount(n) {
  let fives = 0;
  let twos = 0;
  for (let counter = 2; counter <= n; counter++) {
    let n = counter;
    while (n % 2 === 0) {
      n /= 2;
      twos++;
    }
    while (n % 5 === 0) {
      n /= 5;
      fives++;
    }
  }
  return Math.min(fives, twos);
}
console.log(zeroCount(6)); // 720
console.log(zeroCount(10)); // 3628800
```

Comment: Don't think calculation of number of 2's is even needed as that will always be larger than 5. Just finding number of 5's should be enough and that will be the number of trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple, This will help you.

```
function TrailingZero(n) 
{ 
    var c = 0; 

    for (var i = 5; n / i >= 1; i *= 5) 
        c += parseInt(n / i); 

    return c; 
}
```

Let me know if you need help to understand this function.

Comment: This is incorrect - it returns non-integer values like `1.2`, `1.4`, `1.6`, etc., and doesn't make any attempt to check the factorial of the input.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for suggestion , I forgot to add parseInt now I have updated my answer.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you explained how it works - without any explanation, it's not intuitive at all of how this answers the question correctly, even if it does